# Getting unique property from a Collection in Doctrine2 and Symfony2?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have a Many to Many assoc between entities: (Product and Category) in Symfony2, using Doctrine2.

I want to list each Category, and then each *unique* Product name in that category. Each product can obviously be in many categories (some categories are empty).

Here's how I have to do it with basic entity manager methods, etc. Annotations are hints for PHPStorm so that code auto-completion works.:

```
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SomeRandomBundle:Category');
    $categories = $repository->findAll();

    $response = '';

    /** @var $category Category  */
    foreach ($categories as $category){

        $products = $category->getProducts();

        if (!$products->isEmpty()){

            $productArr = array();

            /** @var $product Product */
            foreach ($products as $product){
                $productArr[] = $product->getName();
            }
            $productArr = array_unique($productArr);

            $response .= $category->getName() . "\n";

            foreach ($productArr as $prod){
                $response .= "\t$prod\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

This works out to be 30 hits on the DB. (29 categories) so that's fine. My problem is wanting to get just the unique Product names from the \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection

You can see my convoluted code to loop through the product names, put them in an array and then call array_unique on it. Sure it works, but there has to be a more elegant way.

Comment: I have to put my controller on a diet and feed my model, so Patt gets the checkmark. Ha. Thanks, @Patt :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a special query in your repository and use the `Group By` statement. This will make your code lighter in the `EntityManager`. Below the code in your repo:

### EDIT

```
namespace Acme\PersonalBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class CategoryRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * Fetch unique product names
     *
     */
    public function fetchUniqueProductNames()
    {
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('
        SELECT c.name, p.name FROM AcmePersonalBundle:Category c
        JOIN c.products p
            GROUP BY p.name'
        )
        try
        {
            return $query->getResult();
        }
        catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

`DICTINCT` could help you too but `GROUP BY` is much more powerful:

```
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('
        SELECT DISTINCT p.name FROM AcmePersonalBundle:Category c
        JOIN c.products p'
        //....
```

W3 is not a great doc but at least you get the idea:

- [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)
- [DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Comment: Patt, thanks for taking the time to create a detailed reply. I considered adding some DQL to my repository, but then I thought that there had to be a simpler way to squeeze out the uniques using just what doctrine provides. Yeah, doctrine abstracts the association (for example: the join table), but I thought that Collections may have a few tricks up their sleeves...I guess not. I'll give it a day and if no one comes up with a one-liner for the controller, then I'll give you the checkmark for the valuable info for people from the future to enjoy :)

Comment: No worries @keyboardSmasher. I think it's a good [practice](http://www.slideshare.net/nperriault/30-symfony-best-practices) to keep the code very short in the controller. If you want to reuse the code somewhere else, you won't be able to do it by putting the logic in your controller. Good luck !